# CURLOPT_FILE using Curl library

Tags: codeigniter, curl

It is posible to download a file using CURLOPT_FILE with Curl (Philip Sturgeon) library?

Right now I'm using, it works but I want to do it with Curl library:

```
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('display_errors',true);//Just in case we get some errors, let us know....

$fp = fopen ('/Users/tony/labs/store/'. 'a.mp4', 'w+');//This is the file where we save the information
$ch = curl_init($previewUrl);//Here is the file we are downloading
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

I want something like this:

```
$file = fopen($to, 'w');
$this->curl->create($url);
$this->curl->option('file', $file);
$this->curl->execute();
fclose($file);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think using a Library that wraps curl which by itself is already extremely simple is just overkill.

If it does not support it the library is only a single.php file, you could easily add that one line of code in there and it would support it.